# Problematic Turkish Characters in phpMyAdmin at Media Temple

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using media temple and I create my tables like this using a PHP file (encoded in UTF-8 without BOM):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

I have two situations:

1 - Inserted some rows into table via php code. Turkish characters are displayed weirdly in phpMyAdmin, however when I print them on browser, they look correct.

2 - I add some data with Turkish characters into the table via phpMyAdmin SQL Query tab. This time I see correct characters in phpMyAdmin, however, when I print table rows to browser, I got quesionmarks instead of Turkish characters.

My browser uses UTF-8 as character encoding. I tried "utf8_turkish_ci" as collation for the table but no effect. I changed phpMyAdmin language to Turkish but it didn't work neither. When I export database from Media Temple, all Turkish character are replaced with weird ones. Do I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by using mysqli. I was in a paradox while using mysql extension in PHP such that when I get correct characters in phpMyAdmin, I get wrong on browser or vice versa. I just convert codes, nothing more (connect, set names to utf8 and do whatever you want). Every operation looks fine now. I don't why but changing extension solved the problem.